# how to merge two list having dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'data1': 'Chris', 'data2': ['Salt', 'Texas']}, 
         {'id': 2, 'data1': 'Smith', 'data2': ['Melbourne', 'Victoria', 'Sydney']}]

list2 = [{'id': 1, 'data1': ['Royne','Nick'], 'data2': 'US'}, 
         {'id': 2, 'data1': ['Harry','Jorge','Marie'], 'data2': 'Australia'}]
```

I want to merge these two list and get:

```
merged_list = [{'id': 1, 'data1': ['Chris','Royne','Nick']', 'data2': ['US','Salt', 'Texas']}, 
               {'id': 2, 'data1': ['Smith','Harry','Jorge','Marie'], 'data2': ['Australia','Melbourne', 'Victoria', 'Sydney']}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def merge_dicts(list1, list2):
    merged_list = []
    for i, (d1, d2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        merged_list.append({})
        for d in [d1, d2]:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if k in merged_list[i]:
                    if v not in merged_list[i][k]:
                        if isinstance(v, list):
                            merged_list[i][k].extend(v)
                        else:
                            merged_list[i][k].append(v)
                else:
                    if isinstance(v, list):
                        merged_list[i][k] = v
                    else:
                        merged_list[i][k] = [v]
        for k, v in merged_list[i].items():
            if len(v) == 1:
                merged_list[i][k] = v[0]
            else:
                merged_list[i][k] = v
    return merged_list

>>> merge_dicts(list1, list2)
[{'id': 1, 'data1': ['Chris', 'Royne', 'Nick'], 'data2': ['Salt', 'Texas', 'US']}, {'id': 2, 'data1': ['Smith', 'Harry', 'Jorge', 'Marie'], 'data2': ['Melbourne', 'Victoria', 'Sydney', 'Australia']}]
```